# Qual è il significato di "pesto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Non cadde un sassolino, ma un frastuono inmenso riempì gli orecchi e tutti i sensi di Artemisia, il suo sangue pesò come piombo e il suo rossore, chi ne fosse curato, era *pesta* lividura.

Ho cercato il significato di "pesto" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, non capisco cosa intenda dire l'autrice con "pesta lividura" nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esiste un'altra accezione per `pesto`: scuro, profondo.

A me viene in mente solo un caso comune in cui questo viene usata questa accezione: `buio pesto`

Answer (score 3):

Riferendosi a dei lividi, ***[pesto](http://www.dizionario-italiano.org/Pesto)*** nel brano viene usato in senso figurato col significato di ammaccato, contuso, per sottolineare l'apparente gravità dei lividi:

> - Aggettivo Ridotto in poltiglia o in polvere usando un pestello: aglio, pepe pesto; ***Estensione, ammaccato, contuso: sentirsi tutto pesto ‖occhi pesto, lividi e gonfi per i colpi ricevuti*** ~Figurativo, circondati da occhiaie per sonno o stanchezza ‖ Figurativo, buio pesto, totale, profondo
>     Sostantivo Maschile

Comment: Non mi sembra che il brano stia parlando di lividi, ma del colore del volto della protagonista.

Comment: @DenisNardin - dice che " il suo rossore ***era come pesta lividura***"

Comment: @Josh61: Neanche a me sembra che ci siano lividi, ma che la frase significhi che il rossore del volto (o del sangue?) diventi "pesta lividura".

Comment: @Charo - sul volto non ci sono lividi. Lo scrittore sta dicendo che il rossore del volto è cosi intenso ('il sangue pesò come fosse piombo')  da sembrare "pesta lividura".